# Meteor - move data from one collection to another

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to move Mongo document from one collection to another and I can't get it to work (in server method):

```
var oldData = newCollection.findOne({name: name});
if(oldData){
  console.log(oldData); // this works
  oldCollection.insert({oldData}); // this doesn't
}
```

Another way:

```
var oldData = newCollection.findOne({name: name});
if(oldData){
  console.log(oldData.score); // this works
  oldCollection.insert({
    score: oldData.score
  }); // this doesn't
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Do you get an error in the console for either? You shouldn't need the curly brackets in option 1 - `oldCollection.insert(oldData)`

Comment: please provide the error you are getting over the server console

Comment: @PhilipPryde that was it, I forgot to delete curly brackets from my previous attempts. Please post an answer so I can accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need the curly brackets in option 1 - `oldCollection.insert(oldData)`